# SQL - Return Only Non Null Values From Multiple Columns After a Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

My data has multiple items per policy key with one row per item like the below. The number of items can vary per policy key up to a max of 10 items.

| PolicyKey | Item_Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567 | Bike |
| 1234567 | IPhone |
| 1234567 | Wedding Ring |

I am using a pivot to group items up per policy key and pivot into multiple columns to get this result

| PolicyKey | [1] | [2] | [3] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | Bike | IPhone | Wedding Ring |

As I don't want to select potentially 10 columns from my pivot (i.e. one for each item description) I am concatenating these into one column in my SELECT statement as follows:

`SELECT CONCAT(c.[1],' : ',c.[2],' : ',c.[3],' : ',c.[4],' : ',c.[5],' : ',c.[6],' : ',c.[7],' : ',c.[8],' : ',c.[9],' : ',c.[10])) AS AllItems`

The problem is for those policy keys where the number of items is say one or two, my CONCAT statement will include a number of ' : ' characters (i.e. the seperator in my CONCAT statement) at the end of the cell.

Is there any function that can return only the non-null values in multiple columns? Because the result of my pivot can potentially have say 1 non null column and 9 null columns, I'd like to be able to select only the non-null columns from the list of 10.

I should mention I am working in SSMS 2012 so am not able to use any of the new functions available in later version of SSMS

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show how you're pivoting in the first place?  For example, it matters if the NULLs are always last or not.  `x,y,z,NULL,NULL,NULL` vs `NULL,x,y,NULL,NULL,z`.

Comment: Hi there, the pivot would return non null values first and then null values last. So if there are 5 items, the first five columns would be populated and the remaining five columns would be NULL

Comment: Sounds like you should scrap the `PIVOT` and use `STRING_AGG` instead, for example `SELECT PolicyKey, STRING_AGG(Item_Description, ' : ') FROM YourTable GROUP BY PolicyKey`

Comment: @Charlieface that function is only available in SSMS 2017 onwards, I'm still on 2012

Comment: OK you will have to use `FOR XML` or `FOR JSON` instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005. I strongly suggest you move to a supported version of SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

A brute force approach would be...

```
CONCAT(
  c.[1],
 (' : ' + c.[2]),
 (' : ' + c.[3]),
  ...
)
```

When using `+` rather than `CONCAT()`, if a column is `NULL`, the `' : ' + col` will yield `NULL`, rather than `' : '`

Comment: That has worked a treat, many thanks for your help, much appreciated